# sudo apt-get upgrade not work

Tags: 16.04, apt, teamviewer

Running ubuntu 16.04, after incorrect TeamViewer 11 (TV11) installation, I cannot remove TV11, and I did remove it manually (for every folder and file: `rm ...`).

- now on PC have no TV11 folders and files, 
  but `apt list --installed` shows `teamviewer/now 11.0.67687 i386 [встановлено,локально]`. I did try rebooting many times.
- when I do `apt-get upgrade`, terminal shows `E: package teamviewer:i386 must be reinstalled, but cannot find package`
- and now I cannot install (and/or update) other apps via terminal, and via Ubuntu Store (UI installer), because TV11 package error

How I can remove TV11 from app list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you tried removing your package file by file. But did you try to remove it from `apt-get` or `dpkg`?

Removing a package would usually be done like this:

```
apt-get remove --purge $pkgname
aptitude remove $pkgname
```

To make sure you actually dropped all files related to your package, you may run:

```
dpkg -L teamviewer | while read file
    do
        test -d "$file" -o -f "$file" || echo still has "$file"
    done
```

If you are *really* sure you dropped all files from a package, and assuming purging via `apt` or `dpkg` did not work, you may have a look to `/var/lib/dpkg/status`. Editing this file, to remove your faulty package from the list *could be* considered, if you exhausted everything else, ... Even though as a general rule, you should try to avoid any manual modification in there.

Comment: I realy sure I delete all files and folders with name 'teamviewer...'. I understand, that removing must be automatically, but I have not other variants, I use editing of /var/lib/dpkg/status file and understand it must carefully edit. 
Thank you very much, You are really help me with this solution.   Problem was Solved. 
Now upgrade via terminal worked correctly.